# iOS obj-c uploading image to mysql, afnetworking

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I have been looking for a long time with no success for a tutorial on how to upload an image to mysql data base with php service on and iOS app using objective c ...

can anyone please point me to something i can learn from ? i'm stuck here.

so far this is what i understood

make the image into a base64String

```
base64StringImage = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(SelectedImage,1.0) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

i know how to pass strings to php like this,

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***********/imageupload/ios_upload.php?Image64String=%@&ImageName=%@",base64StringImage,ImageName];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

but it's not working, how can i pass the base64String to php so i can decode it there ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"myFile.png"], 1.0);

[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"ImageName.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"uploadKey"];
```